# Show hide section in WordPress Elementor on a button/text click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to create a jQuery that will allow me to show/hide sections by class on the website when I click on a selected button.

I have tried

created the text/button with css class websites and a section with a css class web, then :

> ```
> $("#websites").click(function(){
>     $(".web").hide();
> })
> ```

But this is not working for me , any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**The new code**

```
> <button onclick="myfunction()">Hide/Show</button> <script> function
> myfunction() {
>     var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
>     if (x.style.display === 'none') {
>         x.style.display = 'block';
>     } else {
>         x.style.display = 'none';
>     } } </script>
```

I need to have multiple values show/hidden. I tried getbyclass and also querySelectorAll. but this is still not  working for me. Please advise.

Comment: You need to add a second `"` to your initial click selector - `$("#websites").click(function(){
$(".web").hide();
});`. The code you've shown is invalid, I don't know if this is your issue or just a typo here!

Comment: I tried with a " and its still not working

Comment: You need to provide your HTML because the code above would work. Please read this for advice: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not sure how to provide a HTML because I am using Wordpress Elementor page builder.  In a meantime I found another code that I am trying to implement. The new code is working with getElementById , but I need multiple values I am not able to get it working that way. I tried getbyclass and also querySelectorAll. I will update my qustion with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to use `jquery` for this - you can add a `click` event to your button and then select the elements you want by a `class` using `$(".classname")`, before then call `.toggle()`.

I've provided an example below, the code is fully commented, all the `CSS` rules are simply to make it look nicer, they are not needed for functionality.

---

```js
// Add click event to toggle button
$("#toggleButton").click( function() {

  // Toggle elements with the class .toggleBox
  $(".toggleBox").toggle();

});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.toggleBox {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Boxes in green have the class .toggleBox, those in blue do not. The button below has a click event attached to it and will toggle the boxes with the class .toggleBox to show/hide</p>

<button id="toggleButton">Hide/Show</button>

<div class="box toggleBox">
  A
</div>

<div class="box toggleBox">
  B
</div>

<div class="box">
  C
</div>

<div class="box toggleBox">
  D
</div>

<div class="box">
  E
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your fast reply, this is now working on Elementor editor but not on the live site.  <a href="http://propersoft.rs/t1" title="example">example</a>

Comment: You need to give all the links a `class` like I have in the example, for instance, to directly take the code from my example a link would need to be: `<a href="propersoft.rs/t1" class="toggleBox" title="example">example</a>"`